# Add Secure notes to Keychain via Applescript

Tags: mac, applescript, password-management, keychain

I have switched from Windows to Mac and one of the things I need to set up properly is password management. Previously on Windows I was using a small TrueCrypt file containing text files with usernames and passwords.

I need to write an Applescript that takes those text files and imports them as Secure notes into Mac's Keychain Access app.

I know that there are *some* Applescript commands related to Keychain, but I haven't found a way to add **Secure notes**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Apple Developer area has some documentation referencing [Keychain Services](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Security/Conceptual/keychainServConcepts/keychainServConcepts.pdf), which include a reference to *Change the attributes and data in a keychain item* (ex. notes) but I'm unable to find any calls for AppleScript outside of generating new login keys.

Comment: It's not Applescript but it is an API nevertheless. Thanks for the link.

Answer (score 0):

Given that you're new to the Mac, I'll suggest something that would solve your issue in an entirely different (and more Mac-like) way.

Your text files are usernames and passwords, right? So, they don't actually need to be notes; they could instead be stored as username & passwords, whether inside your Keychain or not.

If that's the case, I recommend skipping Keychain Access and instead going for [1Password](http://agilewebsolutions.com/products/1Password). If you can get your current text files into a single CSV file, [here's the instructions](http://help.agile.ws/1Password3/import_passwords.html) on how to import them.

Comment: Apart from this initial import there are no features in 1Password that I would miss with the default Keychain Access app. I'm trying to keep the number of 3rd party apps to a minimum, for now.

Comment: @TomA - I think the way 1Password backs itself up to Dropbox is a killer feature, but that's just me. And then again, I also have an iPhone and iPad, so being able to update once on any device and have it sync everywhere automagically rocks my world.

Comment: @TomA - but separately: if I was correct that your text files *are* usernames and passwords, is there a reason you don't just use AppleScript to turn those files into passwords (versus notes)? And here's another option that might work for you: [Keychain Access From Shell](http://blog.macromates.com/2006/keychain-access-from-shell/).

Comment: The text files were all created ad-hoc. Some contain additional notes, fragments of registration emails, etc. There's no fixed format apart from the fact that the filename is a domain name (so the Secure note "title" and "text" format would be ideal). Anyway, I'm probably going to just copy and paste the stuff by hand..